# Why is my if loop is getting skipped while my condition is true?

Tags: java

I am coding a small program where I add an an ArrayList of Strings and I have a method that removes every String ending with S, it is working fine for 4 of elements but it seems to skip one.

Minimum reproducible example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class sList {
    public static void main(String [] args) {

    ArrayList<String> sList=new ArrayList<String>();

    sList.add("leaf");
    sList.add("leaves");
    sList.add("box");
    sList.add("boxes");
    sList.add("phones");
    sList.add("phone");
    method m=new methods(); 
System.out.println(m.removePlurals(sList));

}
}

\\ that is my main method 

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class method {

ArrayList<String> removePlurals(ArrayList<String> s) {

        for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
            char c = s.get(i).charAt(s.get(i).length() - 1);
            if (c == 's') {
                s.remove(i);
            }

        }
        return s;
    }

}
```

I am getting as an output: [leaf, box, phones, phone] so it is skipping "phones"
Any help?

Comment: If you remove something from the list the index is not adjusted. That means you will have to add a `i--` or else you skip an element.

Comment: An easier way to implement this is `s.removeIf(e -> e.endsWith("s"));`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about what happens when after you removed "boxes" from the list. The index of "phones" *decreases by 1*. If it is originally the nth item in the list, it is now the (n-1)th item in the list, isn't it? So now "phones" is at the same position in the list as where "boxes" originally was. On the other hand, `i` increases by 1.

Now you should see the problem, to check for "phones", `i` should remain the same because after removing "boxes", the index of "phones" decreased by 1.

Solution, just loop from the end of the list to the start, and you won't have this problem:

```
for (int i = s.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    char c = s.get(i).charAt(s.get(i).length() - 1);
    if (c == 's') {
        s.remove(i);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because at the moment you remove an item of a list, the list size is less than at the begining and when your counter is incremented, points to the next one element (skips one).
Yous can solve that just looping the list on the other way, as follow:

```
 ArrayList<String> removePlurals(ArrayList<String> s) {

        for (int i = s.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            char c = s.get(i).charAt(s.get(i).length() - 1);
            if (c == 's') {
                s.remove(i);
            }

        }
        return s;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the list you are iterating is being updated in the same loop. So when you remove one element is previous iteration it's index is being updated and element is not picked up at all by loop. So the solution should be like:

**1) Create new list and return that:**

```
ArrayList<String> removePlurals(final ArrayList<String> s) {

    final ArrayList<String> updatedList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
      final char c = s.get(i).charAt(s.get(i).length() - 1);
      if (c != 's') {
        updatedList.add(s.get(i));
      }

    }
    return updatedList;
  }
```

**2) Using Iterator:**

```
ArrayList<String> removePlurals(final ArrayList<String> s) {

        final Iterator<String> itr = s.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
        final String x = itr.next();
        if (x.charAt(x.length() - 1) == 's') {
           itr.remove();
        }
        }
        return s;  
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the issue reported in the question: you have the issue that removing from the middle of an `ArrayList` one element at a time is really inefficient, because you keep on shifting all of the elements between `(i+1)` and the end of the list along by one position - and then you do it again for most of them.

Performance should not be your first concern - slow, correct code is always better than fast, incorrect code - but you should keep in the back of your mind issues that some things are worth avoiding: in this case, it is *repeated* removal from the middle of an `ArrayList`.

A better solution is not to keep shifting the elements, but rather just to move them once.

Unlike the solutions which iterate the list backwards, this can be done iterating forwards, which feels more natural (to me, at least).

```
int target = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i) {
  if (!s.get(i).endsWith("s")) {
    s.set(target, s.get(i));
    target++;
  }
}
```

This shifts each element that you are going to *keep* to its new position. All that then remains is to chop off the end of the list:

```
while (s.size() > target) s.remove(s.size()-1);
```

Or, in a single operation:

```
s.subList(target, s.size()).clear();
```

All together:

```
int target = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i) {
  if (!s.get(i).endsWith("s")) {
    s.set(target, s.get(i));
    target++;
  }
}
s.subList(target, s.size()).clear();
```

Note that this is effectively what is done by `ArrayList.removeIf`:

```
s.removeIf(e -> e.endsWith("s"));
```

(`removeIf` does a *little bit* more, in that it does the removal in a failure-atomic way, that is, if the `e.endsWith` fails for some reason, such as a null element, the list is left untouched rather than partly updated).